# Tool to export contact numbers saved in microsoft access database to CSV format?

Tags: android, database, csv, ms-access

I have large database (500) contact numbers and, I want to save them as individual contact numbers in my android mobile.

how to export data saved in Microsoft access  database to CSV format?is there any tool that can do that ?!

Comment: From Access DB to CSV is possible, not sure when it comes in conjunction with Mobile devices.

Comment: @PaulFrancis what are the available options?

Answer (score 1):

To export a Table or Query in CSV format, you simply use the [DoCmd.TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) method.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "yourTableName", "C:\Foldername\FileName.csv"
```

The above code would simply export the table **yourTableName** to the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

Here https://support.spatialkey.com/export-data-from-database-to-csv-file/
The menu is for Access 2007, any other version would have a similar tool.